# rename files in a directory by deleting just a part of the files names

Tags: python

so i have a directory that contain multiple file with names like "001.ome_s001.tiff" and so on.
i tried this code

```
    import os
  
# Function to rename multiple files
def main():
  
    for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir("mask/")):
        dst ="0" + str(count) +"_s0"+str(count)+".tiff"
        src = os.path.join("mask/", filename)
        dst = os.path.join("mask/", dst)
          
        # rename() function will
        # rename all the files
        os.rename(src, dst)
  
# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
      
    # Calling main() function
    main()
```

but i figured out that it chage the whole name.

what i want is a simple way to delete the ".ome" from all the files using python.
thank you

Comment: The files are in the subdirectory `mask/`, you have to either cd to that directory or give a full path as src

Comment: thank you i edited the poste and i think that what you suggested . but what i want is to simply delete the ".ome" from the files thank you*

Comment: 1. You shouldn't change one question to another one. 2. Just `dst = dst.replace(".ome", "")` or put whatever you want to replace it with (second argument is what you want to put in the place, I did `""` for empty string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not optimal but it should works! Don t use in other context of this one!

```
for filename in os.listdir("mask/"):
        os.rename(os.path.join("mask/", filename), os.path.join("mask/", filename.replace(".ome", "")))
```

To be perfect, you have to use regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add full path:

```
for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir("mask/")):
        dst ="0" + str(count) +"_s0"+str(count)+".tiff"
        src = os.path.join("mask/", filename)
        dst = os.path.join("mask/", dst)
        os.rename(src, dst)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i figure out that this code change the whole name but what i want is to delete just the ".ome" is their any way to do that

Answer (score 1):

Why not just rename the file with a replace?

```
filename = filename.replace(".ome","")
```